# removing redundancy from output columns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

What is  a *NIX way of removing redundancy in a case where I have pairwise comparisons like these in two columns

```
    A B
    B A
    A C
    A D
    C A
    D A 
    B C
    C B
```

`A B` and `B A` represent the same comparison and I would like to remove such redundancy from the dataset. The final result should be

```
A B
A C
A D
B C
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
doit () 
{ 
    awk '{
           key=$1<=$2? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1; 
           if (!seen[key]) print $1,$2
           seen[key]=1
    }'
}
```

```
$ doit <test
A B
A C
A D
B C
$
```

(or, getting terser with it 'cause Chris Down's answer's so sweet)

```
awk '!seen[$1<=$2? $1 FS $2: $2 FS $1]++ {print $1,$2}'
```

which could be further reduced if you don't care about the spaces in your data

```
awk '!seen[$1<=$2? $1 FS $2: $2 FS $1]++'
```

)

The `FS` is awk's "field separator" variable, used here to guarantee the boundaries between key fields will be properly identified.  My original had them run together, `$1$2`, which as Stephane Chazelas pointed out would have treated `A BC` and `AB C` as duplicates.

Comment: Nice. Do you want to add an explanantion of what is going on in there for those of use who are wanting to learn more `awk`?

Comment: @jasonwryan Adding a note about the `FS` usage now, is there anything else?

Comment: you gotta love awk... usually provides clear and concise answer to everyday problems. Nice one, jthill. I prefer the top version, as it's much clearer (to me, anyway) than the terser ones, at first glance

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thanks.  Yeah, perl has better reach, it's not even a contest, but awk is _so_ easily accessible to non-career-IT guys it's my go-to.

Comment: @jthill: rejoice :)  http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html  (but it could have changed since then... if not, awk and grep 's regexp could be a very good thing compared to Perl's ones... But I guess there is packages (or new versions?) with the same approach in perl?). Off topic here, but I just found out about this and it made awk shine again ^^

Answer (score 5):

In Perl:

```
perl -lane 'print if !$seen{join(" ", sort @F)}++'
```

This works by sorting and joining the fields (so "C A" would become key "A C"), and adding them to `$seen`. It will only print the first occurrence, because the conditional clause will only be true when it evaluates to zero (which will only happen the first time this comparison is encountered, due to the postincrement).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care to preserve the order of elements on unique line, then you can sort each line, then sort the lines and remove duplicates.

```
awk '{ if ($2 < $1) print $2, $1; else print $1, $2; }' | sort -u
```